# Why is $\sqrt[4]{4} = \sqrt{2}$

Tags: radicals

Why is $\sqrt[4]{4} = \sqrt{2}$ ?

Sorry for the basic question, but having a bit of a hard time trying to understand this one.

Comment: What is your definition for terms in each side?

Comment: @Harry that's a misleading question. There are multiple such numbers.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
4^{\frac{1}{4}}=4^{\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}}=(4^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}} =2^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $x^4=4$ can be written $x^4-4=0$ and this factorises as $(x^2-2)(x^2+2)=0$

There are four roots of the quartic equation over the complex numbers, two of which are real numbers, one positive and one negative. The convention for roots of real numbers is that the principal $n^{th}$ root of a positive number is the positive real root.

So the fourth root of $4$ which we pick out using the surd notation is by convention the positive real root (belonging to the factor $x^2-2$) which is $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: All the answers are great... thanks to all. But since I'm currently studying polynomials and 'real / complex zeros', marking this one as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

$\sqrt[4]{4}=4^{1/4}=(2^2)^{1/4}=2^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: This one also clarifies it all. Thanks @YTS

Answer (score 2):

Let's give $\sqrt2$ a name: call it $x$, so $x^2=2$. Then what is $x^4$?

$$x^4=(x^2)^2=2^2=4$$

Since the $4$th power of $x$ is $4$, we can say $x=\sqrt[4]{4}$.

Comment: You should also mention that $\sqrt{2}>0$. Anyways, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt[4]4=a$.

Thus, $$a^4=4$$ and $a>0$.

Hence, $a^2=2$ and $a=\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the function $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ for $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ is defined as

$$\sqrt[n]{\cdot}:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty),\quad x\mapsto r\ge0: r^n=x$$